# Is this sentence gramatically correct ? "There is no non existing"

Tags: grammaticality

I have been arguing with a friend for several weeks over this sentence. Is the sentence "There is no non existing" (or any other writings of the word pair "non existing" such as : "non-existing", "nonexisting") gramatically correct ?

In addition, is the sentence "There is no red." grammatically correct ?

And are there any grammatically differences between these two sentences ?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. 'There is no red' is wrong, conceptually and logically. The quality of redness exists. 'There is no non-existing' (it should be hyphened) is meaningless. These questions are not about language; they are philosophical and they are illogical.

Comment: 'There is no non-existing' is not a complete sentence. It needs to state **what** is being described as non-existent.

Comment: ***There is no red*** as an isolated sentence without context is grammatical, but not meaningful; when placed in context, or when extended into a full sentence (e.g., ***There is no red** in that painting*, it may express a perfectly legitimate thought.

Answer (score 2):

“There is no nonexisting”? There is no noun, or at least not anything readily understood to be one, only an adjective. To preserve the pseudo-profundity of the original, however, one might write instead:

> There exists no nonexisting state.

Now any adjective can be substantivized — the poor, the obnoxiously wealthy, the aesthetically challenged — but only when clearly marked:

> In an ideal world, there would be no poor.

I'm not overly fond of this sentence, but because of context and the plural verb, you know I mean poor *people*, thus grammatically, all is well. So you might come up with the sentence:

> The nonexisting exist only as a mental construct.

Now in this deep dive into the intricacies of English grammar, you might have stumbled upon something like this:

> *Nonexisting* does not exist.

Strictly true when *nonexisting* is in italics or framed in quotation marks to indicate its usage as a word in isolation, this one might survive the last beer at 4 am, but not the first morning coffee. While *existing* can be used as a noun, *nonexisting* does not exist as a legitimate English gerund because *to nonexist* isn't a verb. And that brings us back to your original statement:

> There is no [such gerund as] “nonexisting.”

Truer words were never spoken! But to those of us not privy to the beer and coffee, the sentence is utter rubbish.

---

Not so with your second sentence:

> There is no red.

Even without context, you know that among various things in your immediate field of vision there isn't a red one, whether paint, pigment, crayon, or nail polish. *Red* is a substantivized adjective and immediately recognized as such. *Nonexisting* isn't.

Comment: Love the way you wrote your answer, though I am not sure I share your strict position against substantivizing *nonexisting.*  “We can’t escape our existence.” From the first read, it made sense to me as such, though it seemed to me it belonged in a philosophical thread (I also understand the OP was seeking advice about grammar). In other words, despite understanding it, it struck me as odd.